# change root node label of xtext outline

Tags: jface, xtext

The default label text of root node is filename. If I created a filename called `test.mydsl`, it will show `test` as label. But I want to change is to full filename `test.mydsl`.

First I override `createRoot(IXtextDocument document)` to get a `IXtextDocument` type object, but seems filename information doesn't exist in it.

Second try is simply appending `.mydsl` in the end of original text. the weird thing is if I override `_text(Model model)` in the subclass

```
def _xtext(Model model) { return super._xtext(model) }
```

Will give original label `test` as expected. However, if I try to append a string with it, it will fail

```
def _xtext(Model model) {
   val filename = super._xtext(model)
   // or cast it to a string
   val filename = super._xtext(model) as String

   return filename + ".mydsl"
```

The value of `filename` is always `null`. Is the return value of `_xtext()` something else than `String`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a readOnly operation to query the document for the resource and ask that one for its URI. Something like this will do the trick:

```
myXtextDocument.readOnly(new IUnitOfWork<String, XtextResource>() {
  public String exec(XtextResource resource) {
    return resource.getURI().lastSegment();
  }
});
```

Comment: Which readOnly operation should I use to query the document and how could I get the URI for that document resource?

Comment: I added a snippet to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Nice! Here is my xtend code snippet in outline provider class

```
override createRoot(IXtextDocument doc) {

  filename = doc.readOnly([res|
    return res.URI.lastSegment
  ]);               

  super.createRoot(doc)     
}
```

and return class member variable `filename` in `def _text(ROOT_NODE_TYPE)`